# Mathematica Substitution Major Issue

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math, algebra

I type this in in mathematica

```
x + 1 /. x - 1 -> u
```

It does nothing and returns

```
1 + x
```

How do I get it to know `x = u + 1` so it should return `x + 2`?

I've tried every method I could find and none work.

Comment: `x + 1 /. x -> x + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly solve for x in terms of u. Then sub it in.